# Overflow show an empty space horizontally

Tags: css, media-queries

When I use overflow: hidden it hides me the total content of the vertical screen, while if I use overflow-y: hidden to hide only the horizontal content it doesn't work and it shows me a blank screen on the side and the full vertical content.

This is the media query:

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  html {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .nft-img {
    width: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 10px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  #buy {
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 350px;
  }
  #wallet {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
  }
  #buy-btn {
    height: 35px;
  }
  #market,#myprofile {
    width: 210px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  #market {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 900px;
  }
  #myprofile {
    position: absolute;
    left:220px;
    top: 900px;
  }
  #nft-collection {
    width: 150px;
  }
  #logo {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #logo2 {
    display: none;
  }
  .login {
    width: 270px;
  }
  .description {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 320px;
  }
  #navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  #create {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  #creator {
    width: 40px;
  }
  #eth {
    width: 12px;
  }
}
```

If you want to see the rest of the code I posted it on Codepen https://codepen.io/honeygrim/pen/wvqRjzL

Comment: Have you already set the size of the page to the min-width and max-width?

Comment: Yes, but the page remains horizontally movable (without empty space) and if I use overflow-y: hidden; the page hide the rest of the vertical content